# Query several ranges and add automatically a column to know the source of each row

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I am trying to achieve the following in Google Spreadsheets.

First, I want to query several ranges (in different sheets from the same spreadsheet). I tried a formula like this `=query(arrayformula({indirect(E2:E10)}),"select * where Col1 <>''")` with no success

In E2:E10 I have a list of ranges.  Column F contains a name that describes the source of the value in Column E.

My second problem is that I need to add a column to the output of that query that tells me the origin of each row.

If the sources are ranges of 3 columns by country I need to merge those tables and add that country to each row.

Comment: any suggestion? Here is the link to an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GiCnvHAvyXTiK8EyK9srgG7YLMEOaxtwMp3t-ouHwcM/edit?usp=sharing
You'll find what I am looking for in the last sheet where I want to collate the data from previous sheets and add in the first column its origin.

Answer (score 0):

All credits to +Ben Liebrand who helped me out here: https://support.google.com/docs/profile/3464

"I just want to start of by saying that the indirect() function does not work in an arrayformula()  function as expected. So you will need to take another approach. I can understand what you are trying to do so I added another TAB in your spreadsheet to demonstrate another approach. I know it was initially a specific design you were trying so I made some changes to what you had. Maybe you can take a look at what I have offered and maybe you can tweak your design.

I know what I am offering is just very rough but you will also notice that I removed the end row specifier from your ranges in the range table.

Don't assume my example to be the final result but I was just trying to show that the range you were trying to use with the indirect() function will not work.

So hopefully this will give you a new idea of how you can maybe handle this.

My formula also adds the country to each of the tables in the output. My formula looks like this

```
=query(ArrayFormula({
if(len(indirect(regexextract(F2,"\w+\!\w+")&":A")),G2,),indirect(F2);
if(len(indirect(regexextract(F3,"\w+\!\w+")&":A")),G3,),indirect(F3);
if(len(indirect(regexextract(F4,"\w+\!\w+")&":A")),G4,),indirect(F4);
if(len(indirect(regexextract(F5,"\w+\!\w+")&":A")),G5,),indirect(F5);
if(len(indirect(regexextract(F6,"\w+\!\w+")&":A")),G6,),indirect(F6);
if(len(indirect(regexextract(F7,"\w+\!\w+")&":A")),G7,),indirect(F7)
})," select * where Col1 <> '' ")
```

Hope this is of some help to you"

And I hope is useful to the community
Gerónimo