# Dynamically create an embedded array in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398319/merge-multiple-google-spreadsheets-into-one-sheet) merges multiple sheets of the same dimension into a single sheet using an embedded array.  I need the same solution, but with a dynamic collection of sheets stored in column `G`.

I've tried using `JOIN` and `CONCATENATE` to first create the array as a string and then evaluate it.  But there's no equivalent `EVAL` function in Google Sheets so I can't process this text as a formula.

```
=CONCATENATE("={", JOIN(";", ARRAYFORMULA("filter('" & G:G & "'!A2:F, len('" & G:G & "'!A2:A))"), "}")
```

I've tried using `ARRAYFORMULA` and `INDIRECT` but `INDIRECT` doesn't work across array ranges so this only returns the first sheet in G1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("'" & G:G & "'!A2:F"))
```

Comment: Does the answer to this question get you on the right track?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227186/query-several-ranges-and-add-automatically-a-column-to-know-the-source-of-each-r/34311717#34311717

Comment: There's a related question which mentions that, there currently is no formula that's similar to the `EVAL` function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-a-formula-that-is-stored-in-a-cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need "EVAL" equivalent, because there is another alternative: use [a custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) instead. This function code may look like the following:

```
function MERGESHEETS(g) {
  if (!g || !g.length) return;  // invalid input data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  return g.reduce(function(acc, sheetName) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName[0]);
    if (sheet) {
      var values = sheet.getRange('A2:F').getValues().filter((v) => v[0]);
      acc = [...acc, ...values];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

Here you can include your dynamic data G:G as the only argument `g` value. More information about **filter** and **reduce** javascript functions you may find in many sources such as [that](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

With the new `REDUCE()` function you can do this:

```
=REDUCE(, G:G, LAMBDA(acc, cur, VSTACK(acc, INDIRECT("'" & cur & "'!A2:F"))))
```